# Javascript Image Slider - Need to add buttons

Tags: javascript, html, css, web

Please see my code below. This code works fine but i want to add pause/resume,forward,backward buttons. So if someone click on pause, it will stop auto rotation. I can't use Jquery. I worked on this code but i am not able to add buttons to this code.

```js
(function() {

    function Slideshow( element ) {
        this.el = document.querySelector( element );
        this.init();
    }

    Slideshow.prototype = {
        init: function() {
            this.wrapper = this.el.querySelector( ".slider-wrapper" );
            this.slides = this.el.querySelectorAll( ".slide" );
            this.previous = this.el.querySelector( ".slider-previous" );
            this.next = this.el.querySelector( ".slider-next" );
            this.index = 0;
            this.total = this.slides.length;
            this.timer = null;

            this.action();
            this.stopStart();   
        },
        _slideTo: function( slide ) {
            var currentSlide = this.slides[slide];
            currentSlide.style.opacity = 1;

            for( var i = 0; i < this.slides.length; i++ ) {
                var slide = this.slides[i];
                if( slide !== currentSlide ) {
                    slide.style.opacity = 0;
                }
            }
        },
        action: function() {
            var self = this;
            self.timer = setInterval(function() {
                self.index++;
                if( self.index == self.slides.length ) {
                    self.index = 0;
                }
                self._slideTo( self.index );

            }, 3000);
        },
        stopStart: function() {
            var self = this;
            self.el.addEventListener( "mouseover", function() {
                clearInterval( self.timer );
                self.timer = null;

            }, false);
            self.el.addEventListener( "mouseout", function() {
                self.action();

            }, false);
        }


    };

    document.addEventListener( "DOMContentLoaded", function() {

        var slider = new Slideshow( "#main-slider" );

    });


})();
```

```css
html,body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
.slider {
    width: 1024px;
    margin: 2em auto;

}

.slider-wrapper {
    width: 100%;
    height: 400px;
    position: relative;
}

.slide {
    float: left;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: opacity 3s linear;
}

.slider-wrapper > .slide:first-child {
    opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="slider" id="main-slider"><!-- outermost container element -->
    <div class="slider-wrapper"><!-- innermost wrapper element -->
        <img id="image1" src="SupplyImages/WF00/1489007864182_35556.jpg" alt="First" class="slide" /><!-- slides -->
        <img id="image2" src="SupplyImages/WF00/1489008043581_741956.jpg" alt="Second" class="slide" />
        <img id="image3" src="SupplyImages/WF00/1489008288715_503637.png" alt="Third" class="slide" />
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done this way.

```js
(function() {

    function Slideshow( element ) {
        this.el = document.querySelector( element );
        this.init();
    }

    Slideshow.prototype = {
        init: function() {
            this.wrapper = this.el.querySelector( ".slider-wrapper" );
            this.slides = this.el.querySelectorAll( ".slide" );
            this.index = 0;
            this.total = this.slides.length;
            this.timer = null;
   this.nextButton = document.querySelector('#next');
   this.previousButton = document.querySelector('#previous');
   this.toggleButton = document.querySelector('#toggle');
            this.action();
            this.stopStart();
   this.toggleButton.addEventListener('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    this.stop();
   }.bind(this));
   this.nextButton.addEventListener('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    this.next();
   }.bind(this));
   this.previousButton.addEventListener('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    this.previous();
   }.bind(this))
        },
        _slideTo: function( slide ) {
            var currentSlide = this.slides[slide];
            currentSlide.style.opacity = 1;

            for( var i = 0; i < this.slides.length; i++ ) {
                 slide = this.slides[i];
                if( slide !== currentSlide ) {
                    slide.style.opacity = 0;
                }
            }
        },
        action: function() {
            var self = this;
            this.timer = setInterval(function() {
                self.index++;
                if( self.index == self.slides.length ) {
                    self.index = 0;
                }
                self._slideTo( self.index );

            }, 5000);
        },
        stopStart: function() {
            var self = this;
            self.el.addEventListener( "mouseover", function(){
     clearInterval( self.timer );
     self.timer = null; 
   }, false);
            self.el.addEventListener( "mouseout", function() {
                self.action();

            }, false);
        },
  stop: function(){
   if(this.timer){
    clearInterval( this.timer );
    this.timer = null;
    this.toggleButton.innerText = 'Play';
   }else{
    this.action();
    this.toggleButton.innerText = 'Pause';
   }
 
  },
  next: function(){
   this.index++;
   if( this.index === this.slides.length ) {
    this.index = 0;
   }
   this._slideTo(this.index);

  },
  previous: function(){
   this.index--;
   if( this.index <= 0 ) {
    this.index = this.slides.length - 1;
   }
   this._slideTo(this.index);   
  }


    }; 
    document.addEventListener( "DOMContentLoaded", function() {

        var slider = new Slideshow( "#main-slider" );

    });


})();
```

```css
 html,body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
 }
 .slider {
  width: 1024px;
  margin: 2em auto;

 }

 .slider-wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  height: 350px;
  position: relative;
 }

 .slide {
  float: left;
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 1s linear;
 }

 .slider-wrapper > .slide:first-child {
  opacity: 1;
 }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<div class="slider" id="main-slider"><!-- outermost container element -->
    <div class="slider-wrapper"><!-- innermost wrapper element -->
        <img id="image1" src="http://placehold.it/350x250?text=1" alt="First" class="slide" /><!-- slides -->
        <img id="image2" src="http://placehold.it/350x250?text=2" alt="Second" class="slide" />
        <img id="image3" src="http://placehold.it/350x250?text=3" alt="Third" class="slide" />
    </div> 
</div>
<div class="buttonBlock">
 <button id="toggle">Pause</button>
 <button id="next">Next</button>
 <button id="previous">Previous</button>
</div> 
</body>
</html>
```

There are other ways to do it, this seemed like a good approach based on your current codebase. Hope this helps.